# Dynamic height of custom cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have custom cell and dynamic height of label in that cell. Then I add new cell, but height of all cells is equal (the same). My code:

```
class MyTable: UITableViewController {
var height: CGFloat = 0.0
/* ........ */
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let row = indexPath.row
    /* make some action with objects in cell */
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("order", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrderData
        self.height = cell.address_lbl.frame.origin.y + cell.address_lbl.frame.height + 8
    return cell
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.height

}
}
```

I understand, that the question is duplicate, but I don't know, how to make dynamic height.
P.S. that solution must work in iOS 7

Comment: Have a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH25-SW1

Comment: It doesn't work with iOS7

Comment: My fault. Best explanation is here with great samples http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/1518174 It's objective-C but should not be a problem to write Swift-Code

Answer (score 1):

It's not the problem of the code, code is doing what you have wrote. There is a problem with the logic, table view datasource methods are not called in serial order as you are expecting. You should move height calculations to `heightForRowAtIndexPath`to have different height for the cells.